# Whitelabel Error Page after refresh in spring boot web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

I am getting error as after refreshing http://localhost:8080/apiName url.It working for first call after if we refresh page it give following error

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Jan 29 15:12:58 IST 2019 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

My project structure is as follow.

[image: My Project structure is as follows]

I tried putting content of static under src/main/webapp..but didn't worked.

Comment: have you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look like your WEB-INF folder not able to find out.Can you try to run this and check.

mvn clean package && java -jar target/yourapplication.jar